# Custom User Registration form in drupal

Tags: forms, drupal-6

I'm developing website in drupal using version6 and i'm newbie in drupal. I need to customize user registration form and need to show different different fields as per role. I will define three roles for user like student is weather Student,Staff,Alumni. SO fields will also be different as per role.
I used profile module but it doesn't work for me.
So please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module to achieve this in Drupal 6.

Content profile module has built-in support for custom forms per role (from the module description page):

> Content profiles can be restricted to certain roles; **the module also
>   supports separate content profiles for different roles**.

There is a small learning curve, but the module's documentation should be enough to get you started.

There is also a related [Drupal Group dedicated to storing profiles as nodes](http://groups.drupal.org/profiles-as-nodes).